Why is Intellij showing an error that says it can't resolve the "wrap" attribute?
I am learning how to code controller classes. I created the following controller class. It has one getMapping method that returns design.html. I included the html code below the controller code. The problem is that Intellij is underlining the wrap attribute in the design.html file pointing out that it can't resolve this attribute. Ignoring that, I ran the application and everything worked just as expected. My question is that am I adding the wrap attribute to the model wrongly or should I install some Thymeleaf helper plugin.
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredientList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Ingredient("AA", "Tomato", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("AB", "Cucumber", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("BA", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("BB", "Cream", Type.CHEESE)
        ));

        Type[] types = Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                    filterIngredients(ingredientList, type));
        }
    }


    @GetMapping
    public String showDesign() {
        return "design";
    }



    private List<Ingredient> filterIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredientList, Type type) {
        return ingredientList.stream()
                .filter(ingredient -> ingredient.type().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Design your taco</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
        <p th:text="${ingredient.name}"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

This is the pom.xml of the project:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.taco</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>taco-cloud</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.34</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I asked gpt for any guidance but it could not help me with the problem.
